# Re-use ASP.NET MVC 5 logged in user identity in SignalR 2.1.2 Hub

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, signalr

I have ASP.NET MVC 5 application that uses CookieAthentication.

Inside SignalR 1.x Hub I successfully used:

`HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated;`

and

`HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;`

To check if the user was logged in in ASP.NET MVC 5 application and his name.

Looks like things are changed in SignalR and it doesn't work anymore.

I also tried:

`Context.Request.GetHttpContext().User.Identity.IsAuthenticated;
Context.Request.GetHttpContext().User.Identity.Name;`

Both don't get the user identity that was in ASP.NET MVC 5 application.

What is the right way to get the user identity that was set and used in ASP.NET MVC?

UPDATE:
In IIS 7 - everything is OK
In IIS 8.5 - it's not possible to access HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name is always empty.

Comment: Using Owin now? Probably want to `GetOwinContext()`

Comment: Owin for SignalR. ASP.NET MVC 5 Without changes.